# What are the semantics behind single-precision to double-precision conversions? and how do they affect exception flags?

Tags: floating-point, precision, arbitrary-precision, floating-point-conversion

I can't find much details about precision extension algorithms, I looked into the IEEE 754-2008 as well as in some instruction set architectures specifications. Apparently most of the focus is on the double-precision to single precision conversions, which is done by the rounding. Here I'm asking about the other way around.

From the IEEE 754 standard, conversion to wider formats is always exact. Does this mean that no FPU flag (Invalid Operation, Div. by Zero, Overflow, Underflow, Inexact) is affected by this operation?

How does it generalize to non-standard arbitrary precision?

Any pointers to detailed information are appreciated.

Comment: Invalid Operation can be raised by a signaling NaN. none of the other exceptions apply, except that if you have custom formats with a format that is “wider” because it has more precision but it has a narrower exponent range, then you can get overflow or underflow, and the other direction can get inexact.

Comment: Thanks for the informations @EricPostpischil. Is there an official detailed spec that you recommend? Especially for arbitrary precision?

Comment: The predominant specification for floating-point arithmetic is the IEEE-754 Standard for Floating Point Arithmetic. [Wikipedia has links and other information for it.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754)